# OnZoom method not working in MapActivity

Tags: android, google-maps

Im trying to limit the zoom levels of my map, by implementing the `OnZoomListener` in my `MapActivity` class. This listener has the `OnZoom()` method which is called automatically when the user uses the zoom controls. Now in this `OnZoom()` method i have put in:
    `public void onZoom(boolean zoomIn) {

        int mylevel=map.getZoomLevel();

        if(mylevel>15){

            mc.zoomOut();

        }`
Here mc is my mapcontroller.
but this isnt working...any solutions?
thx.

**EDIT**: well...this didnt get any solutions :|

Comment: I sure am curious to see a pertinent answer to this question. I needed the exact same thing, and ended up checking for zoom on every touch on the screen

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? crashing or what ? try to be more specific

Comment: no...it just doesnt work...i set the initial zoom to 15..so i expected that if i zoom in even ince..itll zoom out again...and i can raise a toast like: max zoom level reached...but i was able to zoom on and on...any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any onZoom method to be overriden in MapActivity -- try @Override annotation and you'll see what I mean ... well at least for v 8_r1

Comment: no not in MapActivity but after you implement the OnZoomListener to ur map activity, then u can override the OnZoom method...

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem. Instead of implementing the interface, add the following code in your onCreate()

```
final MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    ZoomButtonsController controller = mapView.getZoomButtonsController();
    controller.setOnZoomListener(new ZoomButtonsController.OnZoomListener() {

        @Override
        public void onZoom(boolean zoomIn) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Inside onZoom. value is "+zoomIn);
            if(zoomIn)
                mapView.getController().zoomIn();
            else
                mapView.getController().zoomOut();

        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```